# batch apex to update mass accounts and contacts

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, account, contact

I have to write a batch apex which will update few fields in all the contacts and accounts. There are few mappings which will be done cross object - like few fields from contacts will update theie value to a field in accounts object for that record. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
global class UpdateContactFields implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
    global String query;
    global final String Entity;
    global final String email;

    global UpdateContactFields(String q, String e){
        query=q;
        Entity=e;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        query = 'SELECT * FROM Contact LIMIT 10';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){
        List<Contact> contcts = new List<Contact>();
        //List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        for(Contact c : scope){
            Contact cnt = (Contact)c;
            cnt.Pardot_End_Date_180_Prior__c       = cnt.End_Date_180_Prior__c;
            cnt.Pardot_Professional_Status__c     = cnt.Professional_Status__c;

            //need a way to pull the corresponding account here because of the field mapping to be done below
            //cnt.Pardot_Related_C_Account__c    = account.Related_C_Account__c ; //Pardot_Related_C_Account__c is in contacts and Related_C_Account__c is in accounts object

    //also need to update few account fields with the field values in account itself

            contcts.add(cnt);
        }
        update contcts;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {email});
        mail.setReplyTo('****@****.org');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account and Contacts Batch Processing');
        mail.setSubject('Batch Process Completed - Salesforce');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Batch Process has completed');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

How can I pull the corresponding account and do the field value assignment from account to contacts? Also, I have to update the accounts as well - should I write a separate batch for that or can i do it in the same batch?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the account records. I would do this through a relationship query, as demonstrated below.

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){
    List<Contact> contcts = [select End_Date_180_Prior__c, Professional_Status__c, Account.Related_C_Account__c from contact where id = :scope];
    //List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    for(Contact c : contcts){
        c.Pardot_End_Date_180_Prior__c       = c.End_Date_180_Prior__c;
        c.Pardot_Professional_Status__c     = c.Professional_Status__c;
        c.Pardot_Related_C_Account__c    = c.account.Related_C_Account__c ;     
    }
    update contcts;
}
```

Note that "select * from contact" is not a legal SOQL construct. You must always specify which fields to query.

Note also that "LIMIT 10" won't update the entire database, only the first 10 records it comes across (likely the 10 oldest records, but no guarantee).

---

Alternatively, if you need to use the accounts for another purpose, use a map:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){
    List<Contact> contcts = [select End_Date_180_Prior__c, Professional_Status__c, AccountId from contact where id = :scope];
    Map<Id, Account> accts = new Map<id, Account>([
        SELECT Related_C_Account__c FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :scope)
    ]);
    for(Contact c : contcts){
        Account a = accts.get(c.AccountId);
        c.Pardot_End_Date_180_Prior__c       = c.End_Date_180_Prior__c;
        c.Pardot_Professional_Status__c     = c.Professional_Status__c;
        c.Pardot_Related_C_Account__c    = a.Related_C_Account__c ;     
        // You can make changes to "a" here
    }
    update contcts;
    update accts.values(); // save changes to the accounts
}
```

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thank you for your answer. I would also need a way to update few fields in the accounts - which I missed adding earlier. I have edited my post above. Can you please throw some highlights there as well. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: @John Sure thing. I made an additional edit for you.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox , however just one more thing - I am getting an error which says update failed on all the records. Should we add contcts.add(cnt); inside the for loop for contacts and then update contacts outside the for loop, or is there any other reason for this? Also, for accounts as well - do we add anything before calling update accts.values() ? Thank you again for your help on this.

Comment: @John there's no reason to copy the contacts to a new list. This pattern is often used because people think it's somehow necessary, but it usually is not. If you're getting errors, you need to add error handling. There's lots of examples out there about how to properly check for errors.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, when I digged deeper into it I found that in my account object, I have one mandatory lookup field as Sector_Owner__c and its filter criteria should match this - Sector Owner: Username EQUALS rmsprd@company.org , which is why I am getting this error - FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Sector Owner can only be on of the Strategic Account Owners.: [Sector_Owner__c] . I am trying to add it in my WHERE clause - WHERE Sector_Owner__c = 'rmsprd@company.org', but getting compile time error as Invalid id field rmsprd@company.org . Can you please help in this one too? Thank you.

Comment: @John It's apparently a lookup field, so it should be `WHERE Sector_Owner__r.Username = 'rmsprd@company.org'` or something like that. You should probably go through some [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) to learn more about development.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, yes that did the trick. Yes that is true - I should definitely be following some trailheads and I am planning to do that asap. Just one more suggestion - do you think i should be getting FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION on Sector_Owner__c field due to some other reason, since I am now getting a null pointer exception on accounts and I am not sure why. Sorry to bother you so many times and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @John A null pointer exception has nothing to do with a FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION. Based on the code I provided, I suspect you have contacts that have no account. You may need to account for this in your query (e.g. `AND AccountId != null`) or your code (`if(a != null) ...`)

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I am already doing that now. I am pulling only those contacts whose accountId is not null and and then also adding if(a!=null), still I am getting this error. I also wrapped it in try catch, however no luck yet.